# In this snippet, Does memory allocation help ? I think its overwritten by *tmpl?

Tags: c, pointers

```
static Token *make_token(Token *tmpl) {
    Token *r = malloc(sizeof(Token));
    *r = *tmpl;
    r->hideset = NULL;
    File *f = current_file();
    r->file = f;
    r->line = pos.line;
    r->column = pos.column;
    r->count = f->ntok++;
    return r;
}
```

They allocate memory to *r. And then they equate it to *tmpl. I assume the location where memory was allocated was overwritten ? Please explain.

Comment: Does memory allocation help *what*?

Comment: That looks fine. With `*r = *tmpl` you copy the structure *pointed to* by `tmpl` into the memory *pointed to* by `r`.

Comment: It would be overwritten if it were `r = tmpl;`

Comment: Can you specify exactly what you want the function to do?

Comment: `Token *r = malloc(sizeof(Token));` does not initialise the allocated memory to any value, but `*r = *tmpl;` does initialise it. Equating with a `struct` does copy that struct, whereas trying to equate an array does not.

Comment: @WeatherVane Minor: "but `*r = *tmpl;` does initialise it." --> more like "but `*r = *tmpl;` does _assign_ it."

Answer (score 0):

The confusion comes from the syntax of declaring a pointer `Token *r = malloc(sizeof(Token));` matching the syntax for dereferencing a pointer (`*r`).  The first line actually means that it initializes a pointer to a `Token` called `r`, and would be equivalent to `Token* r`, while the second dereferences the space pointed to by `r` and modifies it.  So, the full code takes a pointer to a structure, copies the structure into the new memory created via `malloc`, and performs operations on it - at no point is the pointer `r` changed after assignment, only the data it points to.

Note that if `tmpl` is `NULL`, the behavior of this code is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

When you first enter the function, you have this situation:

```
      +---+       +----------------+
tmpl: |   | ----> | Token instance |
      +---+       +----------------+

      +---+
   r: |   | ----> ???
      +---+
```

After the `malloc` call, you have this:

```
      +---+       +----------------+
tmpl: |   | ----> | Token instance |
      +---+       +----------------+

      +---+       +-------------------------+
   r: |   | ----> | Heap memory from malloc |
      +---+       +-------------------------+
```

The `*r = *tmpl;` statement copies the contents of the *`Token` instance* pointed to by `tmpl` to the *heap memory* pointed to by `r`:

```
      +---+       +----------------+
tmpl: |   | ----> | Token instance | 
      +---+       +----------------+   
                     |   |   |   |
                     |   |   |   |
                     V   V   V   V
      +---+       +-------------------------+
   r: |   | ----> | Heap memory from malloc |
      +---+       +-------------------------+
```

`r` itself is not overwritten.